# Process.Start creates a pop window

Tags: c#, process

I've an exe which runs a process to open the DeviceManager. But unfortunately, it asks for a confirmation to provide 'yes' or 'No' which waits for user input for long time and does not continue with execution.

How to get rid of this? I do not want to provide a confirmation again as I do not want to pause the EXE run with this.

`StartInfo.CreateWindow = false` would not hold for this as it just for starting in another cmd window.

Code below:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "devcon.exe";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.Start();
```

Comment: What does the Yes/No dialog box ask? Permission?

Comment: What OS are you using? From Windows Vista, it has a mechanism called UAC, so it will ask user to confirm running the task like this! Sooner or later, the user must pass that popup dialog at least once time.

Comment: Yes/No box - permission box I mean.
I'm using Win7 OS, so should I disable UAC. What can i do better to avoid this pop up and at the same time open DeviceManager.

Answer (score 2):

The messagebox you are seeing is [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) (User Account Control) which was implemented since Vista.

To bypass the box you might be able to try providing the credentials programmatically before launching the process, I can't test but something like this:

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo 
{ 
    FileName = "devcon.exe", 
    UserName = "Administrator", 
    Domain = "yourdomain or leave blank", 
    Password = adminpassword, 
    UseShellExecute = false,
}; 
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Otherwise the user will have to have admin rights, or the password!

The other option would be to disable UAC. However that wouldn't allow the user to do anything they couldn't do normally, it will probably tell you that you can't make any changes without the process running as admin.

Answer (score 0):

The parent process should be run by administrator account.
Also show all code please.